# To calculate every third term in a Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci

```
int Fib1, Fib2, Fib3, FibSum;

Fib1 = 0;
Fib2 = 1;

while(Fib3 < 500000)
{
    Fib3 = Fib1 + Fib2;
    Fib1 = Fib2;
    Fib2 = Fib3;
    FibSum = Fib3 + Fib1;
}
printf("%d\n", FibSum);
return 0;
```

I want to sum every third term of a fibonacci series but my answers is 832040 and it must be 158905...any help will be grateful!

Comment: Can you explain why it must be 158905

Comment: So fibonacci series are: `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377...`. Which of these should be summed and up to which number?

Comment: It should be for smaller than 500000. If you add every 3rd term that is smaller than 500000 then you get 158905

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework but hey, I was once a student too. Still learning.

I wrote the following code in R but you can follow along enough:

```
fib1 <- 0
fib2 <- 1
fib3 <- 0
fib_sum <- 0
placeholder <- 0

while(fib3 < 500000)
{
    placeholder <- placeholder + 1 
      f1 <- fib1
      f2 <- fib2
      f3 <- fib3
      fib3 <- fib1 + fib2
      fib1 <- fib2
      fib2 <- fib3

    if(placeholder %% 3 == 0) 
    { 
       fib_sum <- fib_sum + f1
       print(paste('postsum [placeholder, fib_sum, fib1, fib2, fib3]: ',
            placeholder, ' ', fib_sum, ' ', f1, ' ', f2, ' ', f3))
    }
}
print(fib_sum)
```

Which results in what you were looking for. Lesson time, since this seems to be homework help. To help you out on the path of being a better programmer I would suggest taking the approach of scaffolding (just simply printing out everything after each line or so) when doing programming.

This will help you to see how you program is evolving as you do it.

Is there a better solution to the one below? I am sure there is but since I output the code as I was programming, I was able to come to the conclusion a lot quicker.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Whats the use of the F1 - 3 I don't quite get why you use that?

Comment: The f1, f2, and f3 store the state of the sequence in the beginning of the while loop. Then the rest of the code moves the sequence along and then tests to see if this is the third time around with the modulus operator, and stores the fib_sum with the first number in the Fibonacci series that you are at.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut to calculate every third fibonacci number:
If you want to sum up 1,5,21,89,377 ...then you sum up the first two numbers you have (fibsum =  1 + 5) and calculate and add the next numbers as follows in a loop.

```
fib1 = 1 
fib2 = 5
fib3 = 0
fibsum = fib1 + fib2
while fib3 < 500000 :
    fib3 = fib2*4+fib1
    if fib3 < 500000:
        fibsum += fib3
    fib1 = fib2
    fib2 = fib3
print fibsum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code applying a formula found at [HERE](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html)

```
double phi1 = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;
double phi2 = (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2.0;

int counter = 2;//Third term

int total = 0, term;

while (true) {
    term = (pow(phi1, counter) - pow(phi2, counter)) / (phi1 - phi2);

    if (term >= 500000)
        break;

    total += term;
    counter += 3;
}

printf("%d\n", total);
return 0;
```

**EDIT:** Just realized this was posted OVER A YEAR AGO